# Numpy kron applied to multiple matrices in different axes

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a numpy array (called `op_rot`) with shape `(N, P, 2, 2)`, with `N` and `P` generic integers.

I want to obtain a numpy array with shape `(P, 2**N, 2**N)`, where I applied np.kron to all the `N` `(2,2)` matrices.

I managed to arrive at this solution which I believe gives me the desired result:

```
    op = []    
    for j in range(P):
        op.append(reduce(np.kron,op_rot[:,j]))
    op = np.array(op)
```

Is there a way to vectorize this process avoiding the for loop?